# Type: class extends by abstract class

Tags: javascript, typescript, generics, types, typescript-generics

I have abstract class:

```
abstract class DataType<D> {
  constructor(protected data: D) {}

  ...other
}
```

and class extended by my abstract class:

```
type PersonData = {
  firstName: string;
  lastName: string;
  ...other props
}

class Person extends DataType<PersonData> {
  ...methods with body specific for person
}
```

I need save class Person (and other) in const like that:

```
const DataClasses: DataConstructor = {
  person: Person
  ...other
}
```

i need use it like that:

```
new DataClasses['person']({...PersonData}) // exacly is same as: new Person({...PersonData})
```

but I've problem with DataConstructor type. I don't know how do this dynamically. I tried many combinations and the closest is:

```
type DataConstructor = {
   [name: string]: new (data: ConstructorParameters<typeof Person>[0]) =>
                              DataType<ConstructorParameters<typeof Person>[0]>
}
```

but I must add Person class in typeof. I need this dynamically. DataConstructor must accept any class extends by DataType and returns object to use that: `new DataClasses['person'](PersonDataObjec)`. All clasess has only one property in constructor - data.

Comment: The fix for this is super easy. Remove the type annotation and allow inference to do its job. That is, `const DataClasses: DataConstructor = {
  person: Person
  ...other
}` becomes `const DataClasses {
  person: Person
  ...other
}`. If you need to refer to the inferred type, use `typeof DataClasses`. Avoid excessive type annotations!

Comment: I can't do this. Class DataTypes is use to creating something like plugins. I must by sure the class is correct. I get all extends classes and paste this to fabric function. Fabric function generate views of data.

Comment: Sorry, but I have no idea what you're talking about. All I'm telling you to do is use type inference. It has nothing to do with any runtime function. If there are additional constraints please specify them in the question